# Changing the format of mysql table using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in `mysql` database

[image]

i want to get the result in the following format
[image]

Comment: Is customer name a unique field?

Comment: no customer name is not unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
select
    customerName,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 1 then paidamount end), '-') as `January` ,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 2 then paidamount end), '-') as `February`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 3 then paidamount end), '-') as `March`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 4 then paidamount end), '-') as `April`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 5 then paidamount end), '-') as `May`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 6 then paidamount end), '-') as `June`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 7 then paidamount end), '-') as `July`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 8 then paidamount end), '-') as `August`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 9 then paidamount end), '-') as `September`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 10 then paidamount end), '-') as `October`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 11 then paidamount end), '-') as `November`,
    coalesce(sum(case when month(`date`) = 12 then paidamount end), '-') as `December`
from test
group by customerName
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical table pivot issue, try following:

```
select
    customerName,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 1 then paidamount end), '-') as `January` ,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 2 then paidamount end), '-') as `February`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 3 then paidamount end), '-') as `March`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 4 then paidamount end), '-') as `April`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 5 then paidamount end), '-') as `May`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 6 then paidamount end), '-') as `June`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 7 then paidamount end), '-') as `July`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 8 then paidamount end), '-') as `August`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 9 then paidamount end), '-') as `September`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 10 then paidamount end), '-') as `October`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 11 then paidamount end), '-') as `November`,
    coalesce(max(case when month(`date`) = 12 then paidamount end), '-') as `December`
from yourtable
group by customerName
```

Comment: its not giving the sum of monthly paid amount

Comment: i'm using sum()  in place of max() now it is working fine thanks